# autoresizingMask not responding properly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, device-orientation, autoresizingmask

I've implemented autoresizing mask in all my the views of my project very successfully. However in the last one, which is the settings and there are a lot of sliders inside tableCells, it seems it doesn't work too well.:

[image]

I'm sure I've implemented the thing right

```
slide.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresingFlexibleWidth
```

for the sliders and flexible left margin for the labels.

I've also implemented table reload when the rotation takes place.

The cells are being reused ok, or at least in portrait mode they work, but when I rotate and go back I got what you see in the picture.

Any ideas on what am I missing?

Thansk in advance!

Comment: After the rotation back to portrait, if you scroll the bad sliders out of sight and back in, are they correct then?  Also, I assume you're doing the table reload after the rotation, right?

Comment: No they don't and yes I'm doing the table reload what makes me think about how the CGRect are done for the sliders and labels, which I declare with #define l1 170 for example, after everything is synthesized...

Comment: Dump out cells frame and it's subviews in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Also see this neat trick: recursiveDescription in the debugger: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html

Comment: I'm already dumping the subviews... I'll have a look at this TN though

Comment: I spent 2.5 hours trying to solve that only because I didn't want to add the new frame on the rotation method. It took me only 5-10 minutes to do so and now it works. The only thing that bothers me is that if the user enters the view already in Landscape mode, the sliders will be smaller.

Comment: In viewDidLoad you should be able to detect what orientation you're in and adjust frames if necessary.  Since I can't see any of your code, I can't say for sure though.

Comment: I've been looking around about this. I don't know how to check this out.